# SMSS 2014 Network Server browser is empty

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

I trying to setup a MSSQL 2014 environment and I installed SQL Server Management tools for a dedicated management computer to reach database server nodes easily without starting this resource-hungry stuff on servers itself.

However, on the management node, if i click on "Browse more..." in server address dropdown and i click on "Network Servers" tab, the listing is empty.
Checking it from a database server node, the tab filled correctly.

What things have to running correctly to be SMSS able to populate the listing of the servers (and instances) in the local network?

All computers are a part of the AD domain, the management node is one of the spare DC's (the machine has no other role than being DC, and only SQL Server management tools are installed), the two other node are a member server.

Windows Firewall set to allow any incoming conection from Domain zone, and adapters are configured to become a member of Domain zone, so i think firewall cannot be a problem.

Comment: Can you see list of server when you go to cmd and type osql -L. Is SQL Server browser service running. You must read this link  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188200.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Network server discovery via SQL Browser Service is done via UDP broadcast. Broadcasts are subject to local network segment rules (as in network mask, default gateway etc), so it may be that your server is on a different segment and the broadcast does not reach the desired servers. If that is not the case then the obvious culprit would be Firewall rules.

Comment: Management node and DB servers are in same fragment of same network (it's a /24 subnet without any more segmentation). Firewall is set to allow all both on management and DB servers.

Comment: Use [Windows Message Analyzer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649776.aspx) to capture the UPD requests, see where they choke. I recommend WMA not Wireshark or NetMon, WMA has a lot more capabilities around ETL.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it anyway. I'll report if i can found any new.